# Add Windows Account User to Membership Provider Role

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I want to use ASP.NET Membership Provider with Windows Authentication and Membership Roles.  I need to be able to add a Windows user to a Role.  Can I simply add a domain user to a membership role.  Not sure how to do this.

I dont need to store the user information, password, etc in the Memebership tables.  I simply want to use the Memebership provider for the Role functionality.

Essentially, what I am trying to do is if the user I am signed in with (domain account) is in a "Admin" role - I can see the page.  I dont want to have to maintain a 2nd set of credentials (Windows and Membership) to do this.  This also will not require the user to login to see the admin pages.

Thanks for any tips provided...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options here.

- You could use AzMan with either an ADAM or XML backing store.
- You could role your own RoleProvider
- You could catch the Application_AuthenticateRequest event in the Global.asax page and do a lookup in a table, file etc.

For example here is code that replaces the Current Context users Principal with a generic one.

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Context.User != null)
        {
            var genericIdentity = new GenericIdentity(Context.User.Identity.Name);
            //TODO - get roles from somewhere....
            var principal = new GenericPrincipal(genericIdentity, new string[] { "CanSavePerson" });
            Context.User = principal;
        }
    }
```

Instead of string[] {"CanSavePerson"} you'd look up the roles for that person in the data store of your choice.

- As a final option you could hard code your users and their roles in the web.config.